# ReactNative: Deep Linking in react-native-router-flux does not work fine

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-router-flux

I set up deep linking in iOS using react-native-router-flux.
And I encountered the issue in this comment of mine.

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3083#issuecomment-398651643

It works when the app is shut down, but does not when the app is running in background, only to re-open the app.

How can I fix this?